# How can you search in a UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView with html data loaded in it
Is it possible to use javascript to search for text in this view?
Thanks for any answers

Answer (score 1):

You can search using javascript to find the text. To run the javascript, you would use:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"/* script here */"];
```

I would then use the JavaScript scroll to as it's hard to calculate how the "pixel" location inside the webview relates to the pixel location outside.

The following links may be useful to help you write the JavaScript:

[Example find script](http://www.seabreezecomputers.com/tips/find.htm)

And try prototype's scrollTo code (I'm new so can't link here: www.prototypejs.org/api/element/scrollto )

Answer (score 0):

You could just load the HTML into a string and just search fo a substring of that string using cocoa touch.

Comment: But if I did that, would it be possible to have the UIWebView scroll to the location of that text?